# How to sort the dynamic data generating from AngularJS filters?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, filter

I am trying to sort the shop titles in alphabetical order right now the data is showing randomly. I am adding the fiddle of that: https://jsfiddle.net/jtdk157s/

`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User the filter `OrderBy` and specify the property of the Object:

```
ng-repeat="item in groupedData | filter:categoryFilter | orderBy:['node.location','node.title']
```

Check working sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/bLvLy1sh/1/

With groupBy filter

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, items) in groupedData | groupBy: 'node.location' )">
    <h2>{{key}}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="location in items">
            {{ location}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No its not working if you check with the previous results the output is changed and it is not showing in correct way.

Comment: and what should be the corect way? I can see that the list is sorted by title alphabetically

Comment: But it is not sorting according to the location I mean to say for example &pizza is a terminal C shop but it is showing in separate. So, I need those shops as to filter according to the existing functionality but they need to be in alphabetical order.

Comment: You did it correctly but still there is some sort of error is coming if you see the National hall last shop in the list it is showing Boar's Head Delicatessen which is a Terminal A shop and in Terminal A list the Bracket Room
CAVA Mezze Grill
Green Beans Coffee
Grille District. these are terminal B shops. Some how it is not taking correctly. Can you please check it

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the ng-if check this updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/bLvLy1sh/2/

Comment: Yeah I understood is there any way can you help me out I tried in several ways I was unable to find out. If you can find the solution it is so helpful for me. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Use groupBy filter from Angular, remove the one you create. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks for that I tried to remove the colors and did the sorting it works with your above solution. So, I am assuming there is some problem with that only. http://jsfiddle.net/ka2Lt652/2/

Comment: Try to add the color to a porperty in the array, then it will be easiar to instantiate the color. It will be something like: ng-style="{color : node.location.color}"